# how can i get next available number using shell script?

Tags: shell, automation

I am writing a shell script which will pull code from Git, convert it into Docker images and then deploy it in UAT.

I am stuck in the last part of the script. The problem is that in the server there are several images with the same name with a different tag, like:

"abc1.tar.bz2" ,"abc2.tar.bz2", "abc3.tar.bz2"

I want the next image name to automatically increment: "abc4.tar.bz2", is it possible in a shell script?

I want to create a variable from this formula and reuse that variable later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
next_doc_img(){
    dock_img=$1
    IFS='.' read -ra my_array <<< "$dock_img"
    hotfix_current_num="${my_array[3]//[!0-9]/}"
    hotfix_name="${my_array[3]//[0-9]/}"
    hotfix_next_num=$((hotfix_current_num+1))
    echo "${my_array[0]}.${my_array[1]}.${my_array[2]}.${hotfix_name}${hotfix_next_num}.${my_array[4]}.${my_array[5]}"
}

current_dock_image_name="product_component.4.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2"
echo "current dock image name: ${current_dock_image_name}"
next_dock_image_name=$(next_doc_img "${current_dock_image_name}")
echo "Next Dock Image Name: ${next_dock_image_name}"
```

> Output
>   current dock image name: product_component.4.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2
>   Next Dock Image Name: product_component.4.0.hotfix3.tar.bz2

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you mean  my_array = .tar.bz2....my docker image usually tagged like this: "product_component.4.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2"  and am using following as per your suggestion 

#! /bin/sh
next_doc_img(){
    dock_img=$1
    IFS='.' read -ra .tar.bz2 <<< "$product_component.4.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2"
    dock_img_current_num="${.tar.bz2[0]//[!0-9]/}"
    dock_img_name="${.tar.bz2[0]//[0-9]/}"
    dock_img_next_num=$((dock_img_current_num+1))
    echo "${product_component.4.0.hotfix}${dock_img_next_num}.${.tar.bz2}"
}


echo "${next_dock_img}"

Comment: if this is your current image name `product_component.4.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2` what is going to be next image name ?? for example  `product_component.5.0.hotfix2.tar.bz2` or `product_component.4.1.hotfix2.tar.bz2` ... above mentioned code snippet is according to your question input..  `my_array`  going to hold string split by '.' operator for example `product_component.4.1.hotfix2.tar.bz2` then index [0] => product_component, [1] => 4 , [2] => 0 ,[3] => hotflix2  , [4] => tar ,  [5] => tar and index [6] =>bz2

Comment: my_array going to hold string split by '.' operator for example `product_component.4.1.hotfix2.tar.bz2 `then `my_array  = index [0] => product_component, [1] => 4 , [2] => 0 ,[3] => hotflix2 , [4] => tar and index [5] =>bz2 `

Comment: oh thanks a lot for the reply ....next image name would be : product_component.4.0.hotfix3.tar.bz2 then product_component.4.0.hotfix4.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

1. List all existing names named in certain way.
2. Extract the numbers.
3. Sort the numbers.
4. Pick the highest number.
5. Add 1.

In script:

```
num=$(
  # I am using find as for files, substitute for real code to list them all
  find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name 'abc*.tar.bz2' | 
  sed 's/abc\(.*\)\.tar\.bz2/\1/' |
  sort -n |
  tail -n1
)
num=$((num + 1))
filename_to_be_created="abc${num}.tar.bz2"
```